# How to make image texture transparent

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I am making a white curtain and want it to be somewhat see through. I am using and image texture that is jpeg and not png. and wonder if this makes a difference. I have seen others make objects transparent but I just can't get the nodes to work with this white curtain. Thanks

I should mention that I am using Cycles and Blender 2.79a

Answer (score 1):

JPEG does not support alpha channels. This will mean that the Alpha returned by the Image Texture node will be a constant 1.0.

The only simple solutions will be to either convert your image to a PNG or similar and add an alpha channel or to use the properties of the image to simulate alpha - for example, if the ‘background’ is pure black and the curtain doesn’t contain *any* black then simply use a Greater Than node set to 0.0 to generate “alpha” directly from your color data (ie, wherever Color is not 0.0 you’ll get 1.0 for alpha).